# How to not reference dependencies of Microsoft.NETCore.App for .NET Core console apps?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I have a brand-new .NET Core app. By default, .NET Core apps reference the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` NuGet package; I want to uninstall certain packages referenced by that, namely `System.Collections.Immutable`, so that I can't use the types in them from my app.

How do I do this when the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` reference is implicitly included? The packages installed by default aren't even mentioned in the `.csproj` file now, so how am I supposed to remove them?

Below is the contents of my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Maybe someone will come through with how to do this, but I doubt it. So it might be better to describe the outcome you are going for and someone might be able to help you get there in a different way. e.g. Are you just looking to restrict other developers in using that particular namespace?

Comment: in 2.0, `Microsoft.NETCore.App` won't have any dependencies but a buch of dlls..

Comment: There is no reason to do that. If you don't want to use .NET Core, just target .NET Framework instead of .NET Core or cross compile to both

Comment: Is the goal to exclude the assembly? or just to enforce no code uses it? last one would be a good use case for a roslyn analyzer..

Comment: @MartinUllrich: I just got here trying to actually exclude the assembly so I can ship a privately compiled version with a bugfix.

Answer (score 2):

NuGet supports flags on PackageReference that let you control which assets are installed from a dependency. You can exclude parts of System.Collections.Immutable like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="1.3.0" ExcludeAssets="Compile" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets/ for more details.